# В чем может быть проблема? API менял,в манифесте тоже менял название темы,но все безуспешно

Tags: android

или как восстановить тему которая была?

Attribute is not public. (at 'android:statusBarColor' with value '?android:attr/textColorSearchUrl').
 Attribute is not public. (at 'android:statusBarColor' with value '?android:attr/textColorSearchUrl').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Попробуйте понизить уровень либ поддержки. Скорее всего в них сделали атрибуты скрытыми

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Уроыень либ? не совсем понял

Comment: Я имею в виду номер версии

Comment: понижал,без изменений.

Comment: выдает ошибку и кидает на эту строку
<item name="android:statusBarColor">?android:attr/textColorSearchUrl</item>

Comment: Вы понизили версию либ? Попробуйте ещё android: убрать

Comment: Не так много опыта,но я понижал версию API. Вы говорите про номер версии чего?
Убрал слово android: и его обратно восстанавливает после попытки запуска приложения.
Есть ли способ восстановить тему по умолчанию? так как которая была темя,уже изменена и в связи с этим выдает ошибку

Comment: Версии библиотек изменяются в градл файле, в depencies. Восстановить можно откатив код к другому коммиту если используете гит. Либо просто сотрите все стили и пишите их заново